# Using the output of a function in another function?

Tags: swift, function

i have a fetch request and i want to use the result to inform other functions. the fetch is

```
   func getExercises() {

    guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }
    let userExercise = UserExercise(context: managedObjectContext)

    let request: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine == %@", self.routineName)
    do {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let queryResults = try context.fetch(request)
        print ("num of results = \(queryResults.count)")
            for exercise in queryResults as [NSManagedObject] {
        print("Exercise NAME: \(exercise.value(forKey: "name"))")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
```

The other functions are (capitals added where id want the output to be):

```
    func configure(_ cell: TodaysRoutineTableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let userExercise = THE GET EXERCISE FUNCTIONS OUTPUT(at: indexPath)
```

and another:

```
    fileprivate func updateView() {
    var hasUserExercises = false
    if let UserExercise = THE GET EXERCISE FUNCTIONS OUTPUT {
        hasUserExercises = UserExercise.count > 0
    }
```

I thought perhaps id just add queryResults in there and it would be fine, but as thats local to that function i just get errors. Whats the correct way to achieve this?

**updated to show errors image**

[image]

```
    // MARK: - COREDATA FETCH

func getExercises(completion: (([NSManagedObject]?, NSError?) -> Void)?) {

    guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }
    let userExercise = UserExercise(context: managedObjectContext)

    let request: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine == %@", self.routineName)

    do {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let exercises: [NSManagedObject]?

        do {
            let queryResults = try context.fetch(request)
            print(queryResults)

            for exercise in queryResults as [NSManagedObject] {
                print("Exercise NAME: \(exercise.value(forKey: "name"))")
            }
            completion(exercises, nil)

        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
            completion(exercises, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Being fetch something that you could do in an async way, the right way would be to use a completion block (callbacks).

So your getExercises function could have a completion block parameter, for instance:

```
func getExercises(completion: ((exercises: [String], error: NSError?) -> Void)?)
```

Then, when your data is ready inside the getExercises function, you can invoke the completion block as follows:

```
completion?(exercises, error)
```

This question mark before completion is because the completion block is an optional parameter, so you could pass this block or not, up to you.

Maybe some update is required for Swift 3, just check the syntax for completion blocks.

**Edit:** You will need to pass a closure as an argument for your getExercises function when you call it:

```
getExercises(completion: { (exercises, error) in
   //Do what you want with the result, this is the result of getExercises
   print(exercises)
```

})

Now, inside getExercises you will pass the result to your closure:

```
func getExercises() {
    // ...
    do {
        // ...
        completion(exercises, nil)
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
        completion?([], error)
    }
}
```

Exercises will be of a certain type, not sure what you are handling there, I placed an array of String as example.

Comment: ive tried these and updated the OP with a screenshot, i just have loads of errors? sorry if ive made a stupid mistake im new to writing these kinds of funcs

Comment: Sorry it seems the first error you have is due to differences between Swift 2 and Swift 3. You can add "_ " before the argument names or remove the name of the argument and let just the type.

About the second issue, well, you need to pass the data you want to your closure. Also you will need to pass the closure to your getExcercise method. I'm editing the answer with an example.

Comment: thanks, i was confused as a fetch will return entity result objects rather than array of strings? perhaps i am misunderstanding

Comment: You will need to modify [String] by the data type you are using, maybe [NSManagedObject] or whatever you need

Comment: i have updated my OP image with this code, i am still getting errors for the types?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Use of unresolved identifier 'exercises'

Based on the code you have shown in the image, reason for you first error is that, you have used the property `exercises` which is not declared yet. `exercises` in your `completion` closure's argument will not be accessible within that function. Its a parameter that needs to be passed to that closure.

When you call the completion block, you will have to pass an array of `NSManagedObject` to it which you construct after you fetch the results. In your case, construct an array within that `for..in` loop and call the completion block after that loop.

```
let exercises: [NSManagedObject]?

do {
    let queryResults = try context.fetch(request)
    print(queryResults)

    for exercise in queryResults as [NSManagedObject] {
        //Using the result, build the exercises array here
    }

    completion(exercises, nil)
} catch {
     print("Error with request: \(error)")
    completion(exercises, error)
}
```

> 2. Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '[NSManagedObject]'

This is because `exercises` argument is not an optional but you are passing `nil` to it. You will have to make the `exercises` argument as optional to take both non-nil and nil values. Change your method signature to below:

```
func getExercises(completion: ((exercises: [NSManagedObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void)?)
```

Note: Make sure you handle `nil` appropriately in your completion closure you pass to the `getExercises` function.

Comment: Thanks ive attempted to implement this but still have a bunch of errors, ive updated the OP with an image to show my code and the errors

Comment: It would be helpful to edit, if you could post that function as code.